# Where to store configuration files available in kickstart into custom Centos ISO

Tags: centos, redhat, kickstart

## Context

- Centos 7
- Kickstart

## Issue

According to RH documentation :

```
--nochroot:

   Allows you to specify commands that you would like to run outside of the chroot environment.

   The following example copies the file /etc/resolv.conf to the file system that was just installed.

   %post --nochroot
   cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/sysimage/etc/resolv.conf
   %end
```

The question is : where should i store the file `resolv.conf` in the ISO tree in order that kickstart access it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the file anywhere. The root of the disc will be mounted to `/mnt/install/source`. So, if you created a directory under root called `myfiles`, you could reference `/mnt/install/source/myfiles/resolv.conf` in Kickstart.